# excel power query transforming data from text to decimal

Tags: excel, powerquery

Howto transform a colum with postive and negative values, which is loaded as text into a column with decial values without errors. the minus sign seems to make the error:
[image]

I use a german version of excel 365 on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve the problem: It was q quircky minus-sign, which had to be replaced by a standard minus sign before changing type to decimal. Unfortunatley at first sign this quirky decimals looked like nomral ones